# Apparent poor websocket performance in chrome when running in wss secure mode

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, chromium

I seem to be experiencing issues that suggest wss secure websockets are much slower on Chrome than IE and Firefox. I've looked around but cannot find any real info to confirm others see this behaviour.

In summary:
I'm prototyping using a localhost C++ websocket server  to send individual binary image png frames to a webpage that is opened on the same machine. This has to be the secure wss version of websockets.

I cannot really stream video and use a video tag,as the latency/lag has to be minimum.

One of the potentially limiting factors is how much data throughput the websocket connection will give. Currently just for prototyping, I'm using mongoose as the server. The server doesn't seem to be the limiting factor, it seems to be Chrome wss websocket handling.

Tests on my high'ish spec dev machine just send data over the websocket. Currently I'm not trying to do anything with the actual data that is passed.
Client sends a wss client->server string saying "pull".
Server replies with wss server-client  1 Megabyte binary blob.
Client replies with wss client-server string saying "pull".
Server replies with wss server-client  1 Megabyte binary blob.
..and so on ...

Here are the number of binary frames I get per second for secure and unsecured websockets:

IE (v10)       wss:120   ws:221

Firefox (v28)  wss:65    ws:170

Chrome (v35)   wss:17    ws:93

You can see that chrome wss performance seems very poor in comparison to the others. I've tried this on 3 computers with similar results. I've tried different blob sizes for 0.1 Megabyte to 100 Megabyte and this makes no real difference to actual data rate throughput. I've tried disabling Nagle's algorith.

Has anyone any ideas on something that I may be missing?
Can anyone confirm that chrome wss performance may be poor?

thanks

Matt

---

More info:

After the comments: I enabled '#enable-websocket-experimental-implementation', but it seemed to make no difference. I also tried the latest chrome canary build but this also seemed to make no difference.

More info:

More results on my dev machine (cycles per second) on my dev machine with 64-bit debug server. Sending "pull" to server, replying with arbitrary binary 1000000 byte buffer.
Tried using 2 sockets per client, each on different sub protocol.

IE(v10) : wss:120   ws:221 wss[2 websockets]:176

Firefox(v28) : wss:65 ws:170 wss[2 websockets]:59

Chrome(v35) wss:17  ws:93 wss[2 websockets]:18

IE seems to speed up significantly using 2 websockets. Firefox and Chrome don't.

---

Comment: I have no direct hint rgd your observation, but you might look into http://tavendo.com/blog/post/dissecting-websocket-overhead/ which analyzes wire-level overhead/differences between browsers and TLS/non-TLS. Also: Chrome recently switched to a new WS implementation under the hood (forgot at which version), and that has ripples: http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/hybi/current/msg10506.html

Comment: Another idea: try different ciphers. E.g. enforce a "null cipher" from server side. Not sure if browsers accept null ciphers, but if so, it might help finding out whats going on.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll take a look at these links whilst waiting to see if anyone else has seen similar performance problems.

Comment: I've raised this on the chromium-discuss@chromium.org and will post feedback here if anything major comes up. Hopefully it's something I'm doing wrong ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After feedback from chromium-discuss, a lot of the speed difference appears to be due to the cipher that is negotiated between the client and server.

To confirm this, I tried hard coding the server cipher to SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx,"AES128-SHA"); Then the frame rates are as follows:

Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 m : 49.75
Chrome Version 38.0.2068.0 canary (64-bit) : 53.15
Firefox Version 30.0 : 61.8
IE 30.0 : 68.21

Despite some difference, the speeds for all browsers are now all in the same ball park. In this case I am in control of the server and will be able to decide on a suitable cipher list.